# Factorize $x^3-3x^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found it in a note. I can't see how to factorize it. Using remainder theorem I end up with having 1 or -1. I can't find $0$ anyway. Searching through internet I got a result [in Socratic.org](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-factor-x-3-3x-2-1-0), that says it's not possible to factorize the term. [And](https://www.mathway.com/Algebra) The expression is not factorable with rational numbers. I had seen the term 3-4 times in a note. So I was thinking that they didn't type it wrong rather they just copy-pasted the same function so that it happened? Is there really a possible way to factorize the term?
$$y^3-3y^2+1$$
$$=y^2(y-3)+1$$
tried another way $$y^3+1-3y^2$$
$$(y+1)^3-3y(y+1)-3y^2$$

Comment: All cubic equations can be solved explicitly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula

Comment: Use the Cardano formula.

Comment: Usually, in such exercises, it is supposed to factor the polynomial over $\mathbb Q[x]$ (here $\mathbb Q[y]$) , in this sense the polynomial is irreducible. Over $\mathbb R[x]$ every polynomial splits into linear and quadratic factors. And over $\mathbb C[x]$ , every polynomial splits into linear factors (fundamental theorem of algebra). Yes, polynomials upto degree $4$ can always be solved by radicals, but this gives usually ugly expressions. I doubt that this is the intent of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $f=x^3-3x^2+1$ has no rational root by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Hence it cannot be factored over $\Bbb Q$ or over $\Bbb Z$ in a nontrivial way, i.e., it is irreducible. However, over the finite field $\Bbb F_3$ we have
$$
x^3-3x^2+1=(x+1)^3.
$$

Comment: Certainly not an expected answer as tagged precalculus.

Comment: Even in precalculus I find it good to recall that looking modulo $p$ is interesting. Sometimes the tags also don't match. And isn't the "unexpected" making life interesting? Still you are right  - if the OP clarifies that the field is $\Bbb  R$ or $\Bbb C$, then I will delete the answer of course.

Comment: I would leave the answer.

Comment: OK! It was all about $\mathbb{R}$ numbers. Usually, I would accept $\mathbb{C}$ numbers for myself. Cause, I believe they are solvable using Complex numbers(I don't have much more idea of complex number/analysis that's why I didn't plan to add that). But I found that problem in primary level algebra. But my question is "how $x^3-3x^2+1=(x+1)^3$?" Did you mean $x^3-3x^2+1=(x+i1)^3$?

Comment: No, I mean $3=0$ in the field, so $x^3-3x^2+1=x^3+1=(x+1)^3$ by Freshman's Dream $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3$.

Comment: it is also $$  \left( x - \sec   \frac{2  \pi }{9} \right)  \left( x - \sec   \frac{4  \pi }{9} \right)   \left( x - \sec   \frac{8  \pi }{9} \right)  $$   which happens because the discriminant is a square